# XmlDataSource.XPath, select distinct rows

Tags: asp.net, xml, xpath

I need to select distinct rows from XML data with a 2 column primary key being col1 and col2:

```
<data>
  <col1>X</col1>
  <col2>X</col2>
  <col3>X</col3>
</data>
<data>
  <col1>X</col1>
  <col2>X</col2>
  <col3>X</col3>
</data>
```

I came across the "preceding-sibling" function but could not find any good tutorial. How could I select distinct col1 and col2? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't group by complex keys (other than one node value) with XPath 1.0 only expression.

You could group by one key and then by another iterating with your host language over this XPath expression result:

```
/*/data[not(col1 = ../preceding-sibling::data/col1)]
```

And after registering `$col1` variable (or replacing its value in the expression) as `col1`, use this:

```
/*/data[col1 = $col1][not(col2 = ../preceding-sibling::data[col1 = $col1]/col2)]
```